# Angular directive link function only runs on page load/reload

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement a toggle image [has 3 images src] based on if a user in a list has a filter set, the problem is the image src will not change when when I reloaded the candidates object via ajax because the link function in the directive is only being trigger on actual page reload.

I want element.attr('src' ... to run every time the directive is used and set the correct image source based on doneCondition attribute

```
<div data-ng-repate="candidate in candidates">
    <img-toggle 
        class="like_img" 
        doing='{{animation_img_src}}' 
        done='{{{done_img_src}}' 
        undo='{{{undo_img_src}}' 
        data-ng-click="ajaxButton($event, 'likeUser', {user_id: candidate.user_id})" // register filter on server 
        done-condition="{{candidate.filters.indexOf('liked') > -1}}"> // e.g. candidate.filters = 'liked|accessed|...' 
    </img-toggle>
</div>
```

Directive JS

```
app.directive('imgToggle', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            class: '@',
            done: '@',
            doing: '@',
            undo: '@',
            alt: '@',
            doneCondition: '@'
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<img class="{{class}}" data-undo-src="{{undo}}" data-doing-src="{{doing}}" data-done-src="{{done}}" title="{{alt}}" alt="{{alt}}"  />',
        link: function(scope, element, atts) {
        // Issue: link function runs once so if I reload the list via an ajax button and doneCondition changes the src is not being set updated
            element.attr('src', scope.doneCondition === 'true' ? scope.done : scope.undo); 
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-src` in the template and bind to some `$scope.getSrc()` function. Inside that function run the logic to determine what source to actually display:

```
template: '<img ng-src="{{getSrc()}}"/>'
link: function(scope){

  scope.getSrc = function(){
    // your logic, for example:
    return scope.doneCondition === 'true' ? scope.done : scope.undo;
  }
}
```